# Manipulate using DateObject

Tags: manipulate, date-and-time

My question is about making a animiation using 'manipulate' using DateObject as parameter. I start with importing a file.txt, like:

```
   data = Import["filename.txt", 
      "Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> "|", "CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII", 
       "EmptyField" -> "", "RepeatedSeparators" -> False, 
       "HeaderLines" -> 1, 
       "DateStringFormat" -> {"Day", "-", "Month", "-", "Year"}, 
       "NumberPoint" -> ","}]
```

For your information, the filename.txt looks like this:

> DATE|ZIPCODE|FREQ|LONGITUDE|LATITUDE
>   01-01-14|1011PL|61|4,9023874104022997|52,366754114627803
>   01-01-14|1012JW|4|4,8945593833923304|52,374049723148303
>   01-01-14|1013LC|275|4,8862525820732099|52,302816957235301
>   01-01-14|1013WN|50|4,8738205432891801|52,390252947807298
>   01-01-14|1015AE|55|4,8903188109397897|52,375850826501797
>   01-01-14|1015CR|73|4,8884466290473902|52,302816957235301
>   01-01-14|1015DT|312|4,8770217597484598|52,302816957235301
>   01-01-14|1016HP|118|4,8770217597484598|52,302816957235301
>   01-01-14|1016RS|15|4,8787397146225002|52,371013462543502
>   01-01-14|1017NP|60|4,8856249451637304|52,302816957235301
>   01-01-14|1017PX|52|4,7597301006317103|52,362340539693797
>   01-01-14|1018AM|154|4,9260766804218301|52,367431372404099

I would like to make a animation with the GeoGraphics function: A Google.maps background with plotted some transaction history. So I created a new dataset: data1

```
data1 = Map[{#[[1]], #[[3]], GeoPosition[{#[[5]], #[[4]]}]} &, data]
```

Then I create a Google.maps graphic:

```
GeoGraphics[{{Red, Opacity[.4], PointSize[#2*0.0001], Point[#3]} & @@@
    data1}, GeoRange -> {{50.77119, 53.47875}, {3.437263, 7.187985}}, 
 GeoScaleBar -> "Metric", ImageSize -> Large]
```

I want to make a animation based on the first column (data). For every new date in the file a want to see a new graphic. The result must be a animation. I tried many option. For me, a logical option is de folllowing:

```
Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[{{Red, Opacity[.4], PointSize[#2*0.0001], Point[#3]} & @@@
     Select[data1[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], #[[1]] == date &]}, 
  GeoScaleBar -> "Metric", ImageSize -> Large, 
  GeoRange -> {{50.77119, 53.47875}, {3.437263, 
     7.187985}}], {date, {DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], 
    DateObject[{2014, 1, 15}]], "Days"}, SaveDefinitions -> True}]
```

This script doesn't work. Anyone a idea how I can use DataeObject as a parameter within the manipulate function?

Comment: As far as I know the maps are not from Google but from OpenStreetmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several errors in your `Manipulate` variable specification:

- "Days" outside of the `DateRange` function brackets
- "Days" instead of "Day"
- {} around `DateRange`: this function generates a list itself, nothing else is needed.
- `SaveDefinition` option within the `date` specification list, instead of as an option of `Manipulate`

Furthermore, you have your dates in the input file as "YearShort"s ('14' instead of '2014'), so you have to `Import` them that way using "YearShort" instead of "Year".

The working code:

```
Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[{Red, Opacity[.4], PointSize[#2*0.0001], Point[#3]} & @@@
    Select[data1[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], #[[1]] == date &],
  GeoScaleBar -> "Metric",
  GeoRange -> {{50.77119, 53.47875}, {3.437263, 7.187985}},
  ImageSize -> Large
  ],
 {date, DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 1, 15}], "Day"]},
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For an animation, just change `Manipulate` into `Animate`.